# Restart confirmation reset

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

I am developing with Ubuntu 12.04LTS one application as Gnome-Screensaver.

I can't find process that show a dialog to confirm if user want to close a application when it is running yet, even after restart has been confirmed. This dialog showed three options:

- Lock screen
- Cancel
- Restart anyaway

I need understand it send a command lock screen to "Gnome-screensaver".

Please, Could someone try help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/3539/how-can-i-make-and-distribute-an-ubuntu-screensaver

This might be helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker